# How to write junit test cases for DAO layer using namedParameterJdbcTemplate for parameterized query?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5

I have to write test cases for DAO layer and we use namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject to fetch details from database. We use BeanPropertyRowMapper and parameterrized queries.

DAO layer code as below

```
@Repository
public class GeneratorRepository {


    @Value("${sql.existingUtQuery}")
    private String existingUtQuery;

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private BeanPropertyRowMapper<Generator> generatorRowMapper;


    public generator findExistingUt(Request request) {
        Generator ut = new Generator();
        try {
            SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue("no", request.getId(), Types.VARCHAR)
                    .addValue("sub", request.getSub(), Types.VARCHAR)
                    .addValue("rt", request.getRt(), Types.INTEGER)
                    .addValue("sta", request.getSta(), Types.VARCHAR);
            ut = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(existingUtQuery, namedParameters, generatorRowMapper);
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            ut = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return ut;
    }

}
```

I am trying to write test cases as below

```
@Test
    public void findExistingUt() {
        Request request = new Request("12345", "F", 0, "XC");
        Generator expectedResponse = new Generator("12345", "F", 0, "XC","12345.FCST","345TDGHDF45G","OS01",null);
        String existingUtiQuery = "select Top 1 * from existingUT where NO= :no AND SUB= :sub AND rt= :rt and STA= :sta order by LAST_UPDATE desc";
        Mockito.when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(existingUtQuery, namedParameterJdbcTemplate, generatorRowMapper)).thenReturn(expectedResponse);
        Generator actualResponse = generatorRepo.findExistingUt(request);
        assertEquals(expectedResponse, actualResponse);
    }
```

**How to write test cases for this DAO layer using Mockito ?**

Comment: Do you have any exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not reproducible. So it should look this way. InjectMocks on a class that you are testing. Mock dependencies. Set up environment variables. and the in-test use argument matches. Hope it work.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GeneratorRepositoryTest {

    @Mock
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private GeneratorRepository generatorRepository;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(generatorRepository, "existingUtQuery", "select Top 1 * from existingUT where NO= :no AND SUB= :sub AND rt= :rt and STA= :sta order by LAST_UPDATE desc");
    }

   @Test
    public void testFindExistingUt() {
    Request request = new Request("12345", "F", 0, "XC");
    Generator expectedResponse = new Generator("12345", "F", 0, "XC", "12345.FCST", "345TDGHDF45G", "OS01", null);

    Mockito.when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(SqlParameterSource.class), Mockito.any(BeanPropertyRowMapper.class)))
            .thenReturn(expectedResponse);

    Generator actualResponse = generatorRepository.findExistingUt(request);

    assertEquals(expectedResponse, actualResponse);
    Mockito.verify(namedParameterJdbcTemplate).queryForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(SqlParameterSource.class), Mockito.any(BeanPropertyRowMapper.class));
}
```

}

Comment: Exception in findExistingUt class org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem : 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'queryForObject' method:
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
    null,
    MapSqlParameterSource {no=123 (type:VARCHAR), sub=DCF (type:VARCHAR), re=0 (type:INTEGER), sta=0 (type:VARCHAR)},
 generatorRowMapper
);
    -> at com.dao.GeneratorRepository.findExistingUt(GeneratorRepository.java:80)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(null,null,null);

Comment: getting above error

Comment: Made some changes. Updated code

Comment: resolved the error. Thanks